# PhpFusion install

Tags: php, parse-error

I installed PhpFusion 9.03.20 on my server. When i try view forum, error show:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in
>   /var/www/sp/infusions/forum/classes/threads/threads.php on line 621

```
private static function get_thread_stats($thread_id) {
    [$array['post_count'], $array['last_post_id'], $array['first_post_id']] = dbarraynum(dbquery("SELECT COUNT(post_id), MAX(post_id), MIN(post_id) FROM ".DB_FORUM_POSTS." WHERE thread_id='".intval($thread_id)."' AND post_hidden='0' GROUP BY thread_id"));
    if (!$array['post_count']) {
        redirect(FORUM.'index.php');
    } // exit no.2
    $_GET['rowstart'] = isset($_GET['rowstart']) && isnum($_GET['rowstart']) && $_GET['rowstart'] <= $array['last_post_id'] ? $_GET['rowstart'] : 0; // secure against XSS

    return (array)$array;
}
```

This is 621 line:

```
[$array['post_count'], $array['last_post_id'], $array['first_post_id']] = dbarraynum(dbquery("SELECT COUNT(post_id), MAX(post_id), MIN(post_id) FROM ".DB_FORUM_POSTS." WHERE thread_id='".intval($thread_id)."' AND post_hidden='0' GROUP BY thread_id"));
```

Where is problem?

Comment: Wrong PHP version for that shorthand. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax

Comment: You should also be getting _"undefined variable '$array'"_ since that doesn't seem to be defined inside the method.